# issues with friendly urls using htaccess and php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a problem, but may be easier if i put my code. I have this:

```
<?php
$view = "";

if(isset($_REQUEST["view"]) != "" && $_REQUEST["view"]) {
    $view = $_REQUEST["view"];
} else {
    $view = "";
}

#View Handler
$factory = new \API\Factory();

$factory->Template('header');
switch($view) {
    #Home
    case '':
        $factory->View("home/index");
        break;

    case 'about-us':
        $factory->View("home/about-us");
        break;

    case 'contact':
        $factory->View("home/contact");
        break;

    #Products
    case 'products':
        $factory->View("products/index");
        break;

    case 'details':
        $factory->View("products/details");
        break;

    #How To
    case 'how-to':
        $factory->View("how-to/index");
        break;

    #Tech Documents
    case 'tech-docs':
        $factory->View("tech-docs/index");
        break;

    #Virtual Home
    case 'virtual-home':
        $factory->View("virtual-home/index");
        break;

    #Shopping Cart
    case 'shopping-cart':
        $factory->View("cart/shopping-cart");
        break;
    case 'checkout':
        $factory->View("cart/checkout");
        break;

    #Client
    case 'client-dashboard':
        $factory->View("client/client-dashboard");
        break;
    case 'client-profile':
        $factory->View("client/client-profile");
        break;
    case 'logout':
        ClientLogin::doLogout();
        header("Location: index.php");
        break;


}
$factory->Template('footer');
```

Don´t ask why, lol.  So my problem is this, when user navigates through website he see url's like this: www.mysite.com?view=products, but i want that they can see something like this: www.mysite.com/products/ but i want to manage it using .htaccess how can i implement that .htaccess to rewrite those ugly url's into nice url's. And asuming that all view requests are handled through that index.php

Also want to see it in my localhost, http://localhost:8080/index.php?view=products to http://localhost:8080/products/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this (replaced `$_REQUEST["view"]` by `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`):

```
if(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) != "" && $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) {
    $view = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];
} else {
    $view = "";
}
```

Comment: Don't use comments when you can simply "edit" your answer with the new information.

Comment: @Battal39 with that users will be able to see friendly urls?, cuase i change it but nothing happens, i want to create the .htaccess for those urls. So when user clicks in products instead of seeing this: http://localhost:8080/mysite/index.php?view=products they can see this: http://localhost:8080/mysite/products/